# How to wait for multiple HTTP calls to be completed in Angular with RXJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In this demo application we have following structure:

- List of articles (loaded when page loads)
- Each article has a nested object called detail, loaded lazily

Clicking on an article item loads its details.

But the problem I face is the export button (simulated in this case). The initial export doesn't contain the article details. If I export again a couple of seconds later, the details are included too.

The delays in the article service simulate some latency in http calls.
What is the correct way to solve this? I know this is working when adding some delay(), but I don't like this solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-riqbsz?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `CombineLatest` from RxJs

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nmpzez?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Note: I also changed LoadDetailsArticle to return an observable.

You need to create an array of observables and pass it to combineLatest function.
once all of the observables return their latest values will be used to be returned to subscription.

```
  simulateExport() {
    // create empty array to pass to combineLatest
    let loadDetailsForArticlesArray = [];

    this.articleService.articles$.subscribe(articles => {
      articles.forEach(article => {
        //push each observable to array
        loadDetailsForArticlesArray.push(
          this.articleService.loadDetailsForArticle(article)
        );
      });
    });

    // wait for all observables to resolve.
    combineLatest(loadDetailsForArticlesArray).subscribe(res => {
      this.allArticleDetailsLoaded.next(true);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have `*ngIf="(allArticleDetailsLoaded$ | async)"` conditionally loading your articles after you've made the requests to get the details. If you want to ensure that the details are included in the articles before you download, you can simply hide or disable the export button until the details are loaded ie the `allArticleDetailsLoaded$` behavior subject emits true.

What you have

```
<button *ngIf="(articleService.articles$ | async)" (click)="simulateExport()">
    Export Articles into file
</button>
```

What you should have

```
<button *ngIf="(allArticleDetailsLoaded$ | async)" (click)="simulateExport()">
    Export Articles into file
</button>
```

Comment: Your suggestion is working, but this is a different approach. The export button should always be visible when the articles are loaded (otherwise it is required to click on each article the load the details). When clicking on the export button, it should load the details where details are not loaded yet and then do the export.

Comment: That's a lot more information than your original question xD

Comment: Sorry for that :)